# rand() not generating random numbers after modulo operation

Tags: c

I'm taking a C refresher and took on a board game as an exercise. The board game is "Game of the Generals" and is pretty much like chess as it uses pieces with ranks on an 8x8 square.

Basically the implementation of a board is a two-dimensional array of a particular struct. So a square of the board can be accessed through its indices, much like an x-y coordinate system.

Now I decided to randomly distribute the pieces across the board, and the logic is to generate a random x-y coordinate, check if a piece already resides on those coordinates on the board, and populate it with a piece if it is available. If it is not, then another random x-y coordinate is generated. This goes on until all pieces are accounted for.

I'm using rand() to generate random numbers within a specific range (I'm using a modulo operator and a padding number to dictate the range. See code below)

But rand() doesn't seem to give random enough numbers for me to work with. I keep ending up with the same piece distribution over and over again! (But interesting enough, I can generate a different distribution on a Mac, but the distribution is still consistent!)

See code below as to how I'm using rand() to generate a number with a range.

```
void initPieces(){

    int player, rank_index, population, rand_min, rand_x, rand_y;

    for(player = 1; player <= 2; player++){

       if(player == 1){
            rand_min = 5;
        }else{
           rand_min = 1;
        }

        for(rank_index = 0; ir < sizeof ranking/sizeof ranking[0]; rank_index++){

            for(population = 0; population < getRank(rank_index)->population; population++){

               do{
                   rand_x = (rand() % 8) + 1;
                   rand_y = (rand() % 4) + rand_min;

               }while((getGrid(rand_x,rand_y))->has_piece == 1);

               assignPiecetoGrid(player,rank_index,rand_x,rand_y);

            }

       }

   }

}
```

Comment: Are you seeding the generator with `srand()` somewhere?

Comment: I love it when someone deletes my comments. Is that an admin thing?

Comment: Is this *actual* compilable code ? It doesn't look like this would even compile to me, e.g. `for(population = 0; population < getRank(rank)index)->population; population++)` ?

Comment: @Paul R: Maybe there´s a `define getRank(a) *(a +` lurking in there? :) Nah, I agree of course, code looks weird.

Comment: Sorry Paul. Its supposed to be `getRank(rank_index)`. Just hit the wrong key when I edited it (its `ri` in actual code. Just made it more readable here. Yeah I know, I should've used `rank_index` from the very beginning :) )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to realize that `rand()` is a [pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), and it is specifically engineered to return the *same* sequence of numbers for a given *seed*. The seed is set with the `srand()` function.

```
srand(0);
printf("the first rand() with seed 0 is %d\n", rand());
srand(1);
printf("the first rand() with seed 1 is %d\n", rand());
srand(0);
printf("the first rand() with seed 0 is still %d\n", rand());
```

So, the way to make it less predictable is generally to re-seed it from something a bit more random, or at least from something that is not the same every time you run the program:

`srand(time(NULL));`

Comment: +1 for the full answer. Just remind that a call similar to srand ( time(NULL) ); is needed.

Comment: @nyarlathotep: Good point, I guess I confused myself. :) Edited in, thanks guys.

Comment: Just clarifying for the OP: seeding should be done only *once*, at the beginning of the program. If your program is run frequently (more than once a second), you will need to find an alternate, platform-specific source of seed values, such as /dev/random or /dev/urandom on UNIX. On Windows, if the time is not sufficient, you can seed using CryptGenRandom().

Comment: @unwind Thanks, buddy! Clear and concise. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to initialize / seed the random number generator:

```
#include <time.h>

srand(time(NULL));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't seed the pseudo random number generator, it is like if you called in the start of your program:

```
srand(1);
```

You can call `srand` with an argument that depends on the time so that two successive calls
of your program would generate different numbers:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because you dind't "initialize" the rand().
Try to do something like that `srand (time(NULL)) ;`

You have also to include `time.h`

Answer (score 1):

you should use [srand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/) to seed your random generator.

A common random seeding is `srand ( time(NULL) );`

Answer (score 0):

Call this once:

```
srand (time(NULL));
```

to initialise before calling `rand()`

Answer (score 0):

Random number generator must be initialized with random seed. See `srand()` function. Often it  initialized with time: `srand(time(NULL))`.

Answer (score 0):

All answers are correct, you need to seed the rand function with something like

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

But why?

´rand´ is a so called pseudo random number generator. That means that the numbers are not really random, but the function uses an algorithm that produces a sequence of numbers that have similar characteristics to random numbers, especially concerning uniform distribution.

This means that when using the same seed, the same sequence will be produced. This is why those generators are also called deterministic random number generators.

Seeding it will provide a different start value and therefore result in different number sequences.