# C generate random address from different arrays

Tags: c

I have the following code. What I want to accomplish is to "generate" a random Name/Address/Zip from all the arrays in the header files. The problem is I get the same address any time so I do something wrong.

```
xtmtrx@server:~/coding/c/work$ ./randaddr
Olivier|Suh|28 King Street Apt 21|11934
xtmtrx@server:~/coding/c/work$ ./randaddr
Olivier|Suh|28 King Street Apt 21|11934
xtmtrx@server:~/coding/c/work$ ./randaddr
Olivier|Suh|28 King Street Apt 21|11934
xtmtrx@server:~/coding/c/work$
```

randaddr.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "first.h"
#include "last.h"
#include "streets.h"
#include "zips.h"

int main() {
    const size_t firsts_count = sizeof(firsts) / sizeof(firsts[0]);
    const size_t lasts_count = sizeof(lasts) / sizeof(lasts[0]);
    const size_t streets_count = sizeof(streets) / sizeof(streets[0]);
    const size_t zips_count = sizeof(zips) / sizeof(zips[0]);
    printf("%s|%s|%s|%s\n", firsts[rand() % firsts_count], lasts[rand() % lasts_count], streets[rand() % streets_count], zips[rand() % zips_count]);
    return 0;
}
```

first.h

```
const char *firsts[] = {
        "Asgar",
        "Aadit",
        "Aanand",
        "Aaron",
        "Aarti",
        "Aasha",
        "Abby",
        "Abdel",
        "Abdoulaye"
};
```

last.h

```
const char *lasts[] = {
        "ALI",
        "ALZAYED",
        "ARSAN",
        "Abdelmaseeh",
        "Abdulla",
        "Abebe",
        "Aber",
        "Abeshi",
        "Abraham"
};
```

streets.h

```
const char *streets[] = {
        "1000 Park Ave",
        "1001 Park Avenue",
        "1003 St. Nicholas Ave.",
        "100 Bleecker St",
        "100 E31st St",
        "100 East 68th Street Apt. 14E",
        "100 Jane St.",
        "100 Jane St PH-J",
        "100 John St. Apt 2208"
};
```

zips.h

```
const char *zips[] = {
        "00501",
        "00544",
        "06390",
        "10001",
        "10002",
        "10003",
        "10004",
        "10005",
        "10006"
};
```

Comment: call `srand(time(NULL))` first, second use [`M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1)`](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html) to generate random number within range `[M, N]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rand() not generating random numbers after modulo operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724582/rand-not-generating-random-numbers-after-modulo-operation). Minimum search effort for "rand is not working" would have given any number of identical questions with answers...

Comment: I did search, and no, is not duplicate.

Comment: google: [rand() generates same values in C](https://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy-ab&q=rand()+generates+same+values+in+C&oq=rand()+generates+same+values+in+C&gs_l=serp.3...4040.5442.1.5680.5.5.0.0.0.0.718.2010.5-2j1.3.0...0.0...1c.1.17.psy-ab.x5p1fjhajNs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=64800bba27e4b1f2&biw=1410&bih=740) click on first link :), What @Lundin says you didn't put effort to solve yourself, its very command bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you haven't *seeded* the random-number generator.

A common simple way to do this is to call:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

*before* the first call to `rand()`.

This uses the [`srand()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/srand) (for "seed random", I guess) function, passing it a number (the current time) that is likely to be different every time you run the program.

Read the [wikipedia article on pseudorandom number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) for more information on what goes under the hood. Randomness is hard.

Comment: Wow! How could I forget? :)

Answer (score 3):

This is because rand() starts generating pseudo random numbers using the same [seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) every time you invoke the program.

call srand() once at the start of main() to initialize the seed to different values, e.g.

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

(As time() have a resolution of seconds, you'll get the same random numbers if you invoke the program several times within the same second) Another alternative could be

```
srand((int)getpid());
```